# what language should be used to make a website which will combine or work with the browser?

Tags: browser

what language should be used to make a website or a webpage which will combine with the browser or the add-ons installed in the browser or the website can even takeover control of the browser ? Is there any language ?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: Takeover control of the browser...how is this a good thing?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the language as a factor in your question. Browsers use well-defined interfaces. Software that interacts with a browser can be written in any language as long as it supports those interfaces.

Beyond that, you would need to better define what is meant by "combine with the browser". Having websites "takeover control" of the browser is a dangerous thing and, in general terms, is not allowed.

However, there are plug ins that can be downloaded and installed and will work with the browser. Again, you need to be much more specific about the task you are talking about.

Comment: I just want to know that which programming language should be used (i.e-php,javascript,ajax etc) that will make webpage work with the browser (i.e-if you give a command from the webpage to change the browser setting, the webpage will change the setting.)

Answer (score 0):

Without more information its tough to answer this.

For code that runs on the browser look at javascript or better yet [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) which allows a lot more functionality and handles a lot of the cross browser problems for you.

If you're looking to get further integration going then you're going to have to take a different route for each browser.  Firefox allows you to develop [add-ons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Add-on_(Mozilla)) to add functionality to the browser, as does chrome.  For IE you'll have to look at [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX)

However for anything more than simple javascript you're going to have to get your users to allow your site to install whatever addons you use.  Most users, myself included, wouldn't allow your site to install additional content on their browsers unless they really trusted the site and there was a strong functional incentive to use the code.

Comment: I just want to know that which programming language should be used (i.e-php,javascript,ajax etc) that will make webpage work with the browser (i.e-if you give a command from the webpage to change the browser setting, the webpage will change the setting.)